# Entity record is created but lookup field stays empty

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to create an Incident record with some Service Activity related ones attached.

For this, I leverage the `RelatedEntities` property as follows:

```
// (stripped to the essential)
Entity myRecord = new Entity("incident");

foreach(var e in myData.Select(record => record.ToEntityReference()) // (1) below
{
    Entity relatedRecord = new Entity("serviceappointment");
    // mandatory fields are set here (omitted)
    relatedRecord["new_mylookup"] = 
        new EntityReference(e.LogicalName, e.Id) { Name = e.Name };

    myRecord.RelatedEntities.Add(relatedRecord);
}
service.Execute(new CreateRequest(){ Target = myRecord });
```

(1): `myData` is a `IQueryable<Entity>` which picks some records out from a custom entity. Data is 101% correct (I already inspected it).

The outcome of this code is:

1. The `incident` is created
2. The `serviceappointment` records are created, *but my new_mylookup attribute is empty*. All other fields are perfectly fine and filled with my data.

I see no errors whatsoever, neither during the execution of the code nor in the server trace. As far as the lookup field goes, it's a common lookup (no scripts, no plugins) set as Recommended.

What's wrong with the code ?

NOTE: removing the `Name` from `new EntityReference(e.LogicalName, e.Id) { Name = e.Name };` doesn't change anything: `new EntityReference(e.LogicalName, e.Id);` still doesn't fill the lookup.

Comment: +1 for correctly assigned blame - others! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a co-worker of mine added an `onLoad` script which inadvertently was blanking out the same field I was setting. My code worked from the start.